# mysql GROUP BY with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have table where date is stored as 3 columns in the table, i.e as below

```
`periodYear`
`periodMonth` 
`billDay`
```

Which is causing me problems, when i want to generate reports based on the DATE which is a combination of above three. for example

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total,  
FROM invoice 
WHERE `periodYear` = 2014, 
GROUP BY `billDay`,`periodMonth`,`periodYear`
```

Can somebody help me to explain how to solve this problem ?

For example I want to list all the totals last year on daily base,

If it's a date column, I could have just group by date, but in this case I don't know how to do that, because if you group by billday,..,., then it going group based on the day not DATE.. you see what I mean ?

Comment: what problems are you encountering? *I believe those extra commas are typos, right?*

Comment: What's the type of those columns? Numeric or character-based?

Comment: for example i want to list all the totals for the bill day last year on daily base, if its a date coloum i could have just group by date, but in this case i dont know how to do that , becos if you group by billday,..,., then it going group based on the day not DATE.. you see what i mean ?

Comment: smallint(4) all are integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just concatenate the values together and then group on that:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total FROM invoice
WHERE periodYear=2014
GROUP BY CONCAT(billDay, '-', periodMonth, '-', periodYear)
```

Or if you would want to convert to and actual date format for easier sorting afterwards:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total FROM invoice
WHERE periodYear=2014
GROUP BY CONCAT(periodYear,
                '-',
                LPAD(periodMonth, 2, '00'),
                '-',
                LPAD(billDay, 2, '00')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) as Total  FROM invoice WHERE `periodYear`=2014 GROUP BY CONCAT(periodYear, '-', periodMonth, '-', billDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is just the opposite of what you've tried.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as 'Total'
FROM `invoice`
WHERE `periodYear` = 2014
GROUP BY `periodYear`, `periodMonth`, `billDay`
```

This will group first by year, then by month, then by day. Biggest to smallest.